# js, $.inArray, not returning expected returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, match

I want to ask a question why this is not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/2FMue/4/

```
var a = $('input').attr('value').split(',');

if(a instanceof Array) alert(1);

if($.inArray($('#id').text(), a)) alert(2);

if($.inArray('United State', a)) alert(3);

// a is array but no return correct match.
```

I split a value into array and use $.inArray to check where a string has in the array.

But it will not return correct index.

I dont know what is wrong in the example. Please advice.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It works perfectly well.

`$.inArray` returns index of the element found in the given array (or `-1` if not found).

As an example,

```
$.inArray("United State", ["United State", "America"]) ===  0
$.inArray("Unknown", ["United State", "America"])      === -1
```

So, in order to check if the element exists in the array you have to use:

```
if ($.inArray("Unknown", ["United State", "America"]) > -1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the DOCS :

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 ==
>   false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value
>   within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than)
>   -1.

so :

```
if( $.inArray($('#id').text(), a) != -1) alert(2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got why now.

Answer (score 2):

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 2):

Is the search term the first element in your array by any chance? This would return 0, which javascript treats as false. Your if statement should be:

```
if($.inArray($('#id').text(), a) < 0) alert(2);
```

Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 1):

Arrays from a split are 0 based indexed, and the string you are asking for is the first one, so it returns a 0 value - which is falsy, so  your alerts inside the conditional do not fire because you are getting the 0 index from the inArray.

change your input value to "fred,United State, America" and you will see it alert.